# How to use 'root = ' in Obnam?

Tags: linux, scripting, debian, backup

Using obnam 1.4 how do I get both /etc and /var in the same root to enable me to back them up please?

I've tried 'root = /etc, /var' which backs up /etc but not /var, and I've googled without success.

This is to be used on Debian 7, under Linux.

Answer (score 0):

Have a try with obnam 1.5 or later, these work fine for me.
You should also make sure that obnam has the right to access those paths (i.e. the user executing obnam has)